# closed event in console application

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-7.0

How Can I Run a function after my C# console application closed?
I want to delete the exe and other files in debug folder after I close the console, and I can not do it when its running.
so I don't know how to do it,
thanks all
It does not have closed event;

Comment: how are you running and closing the app?

Comment: Its in the startup folder of the windows

Comment: Do you want to delete the exe of the same app from the exact location where it runs? or a different app? May I know why you have Debug folder to run the app? Is this a production app or just a POC?

Comment: its not finished yet, so its in my debug folder, after that it will be placed in startup folder, and yes, I want to delete the same app that is running from the same folder that is running from, I want a self destroyer to be exact. I don't know what a POC is

Comment: Try Visual Studio pre build event.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this cannot be done for the same process. But you could achieve this by having a different application like a background services or console app which kind of keep on monitoring the whether your application is running or existed. And run the required cleanup task when your application exited. you can also use Windows Task Scheduler in this case.

Last but not least be cautious when you are deleting something.

Comment: @KianFeizbahr have you tried this?